# Handling None when adding numbers

Tags: python, nonetype

I would like to perform addition of 2 integers, which can also be None, with the following results:

```
add(None, None) = None
add(None, b) = b
add(a, None) = a
add(a, b) = a + b
```

What is the most pythonic, concise expression for this?
So far I have:

```
def add1(a, b):
    if a is None:
        return b
    elif b is None:
        return a
    else:
        return a + b
```

or

```
def add2(a, b):
    try:
        return a + b
    except TypeError:
        return a if a is not None else b
```

Is there any shorter way to achieve it?

Comment: Both of the numbers can be either `int` or `None`. Also after this change it will incorrectly return None for (0, None)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is reasonably compact and can handle different numbers of terms:

```
def None_sum(*args):
    args = [a for a in args if not a is None]
    return sum(args) if args else None
```

Comment: I believe that this is the general answer, well suited for this kind of problem. So I second this.

Answer (score 11):

## With boolean logic:

Here's a Pythonic method, using lazy `or`:

```
def add(a, b):
    return (a or 0) + (b or 0)
```

## With filter

For an arbitrary number of summands, you could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def add(*p):
    return sum(filter(None, p))

print(add(3))
# 3
print(add(3, 5))
# 8
print(add(3, 5, 7))
# 15
print(add(3, None))
# 3
print(add(None))
# 0
print(add(None, 0))
# 0
```

## With an exception

Note that the previous implementations will return `0` for `add(None, None)`. This is the expected mathematical result of an [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).

Returning `None` is suprising and might lead to `TypeError`s when you use the output of `add`.

One way to achieve the desired behaviour when users don't input any valid summand is to throw an exception:

```
def add(*p):
    summands = list(filter(None, p))
    if not summands:
        raise ValueError("There should be at least one defined value.")
    return sum(summands)

print(add(3))
# 3
print(add(3, 5))
# 8
print(add(3, 5, 7))
# 15
print(add(3, None))
# 3
print(add(None, 0))
# 0
print(add(0))
# 0
print(add(None))
# ValueError: There should be at least one defined value
print(add())
# ValueError: There should be at least one defined value
```

Comment: I know it can be written this way when add(None, None) is expected to be 0, but it's not what I wanted.

Comment: @michailgames: Just curious, why do you need it?

Comment: I need to present the sum of numbers provided by users (which may be filled or not), if at least one of them is given, and act differently when none of them is provided yet (this is different case than 0).

Comment: @michailgames: I'd say that you should throw an exception in that case.

Comment: Generally, I agree with throwing an exception. But sometimes (e.g. when you need to process lots of data first, and then generate some sort of summary from it) interrupting a flow via exception is not an option.

Comment: @michailgames: Thanks for the explanation, it seems to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
def add(a,b):
    a = 0 if not a else a
    b = 0 if not b else b
    return a+b
```

Comment: This does not satisfy add(None, None) = None